# selenium get local storage for different domain

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.get("website.com")
#website.com stores a value in localstorage for domain domain.com with key `specialinfo`
#need to get value of local storage 
#this only returns local storage of website.com
driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage")
```

I am using selenium to go to a website.  Upon entering this website, it stores a key/value pair in `local storage` with value `specialinfo` on domain `domain.com` I am not able to find a way to access this data with selenium as `driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage")` only returns the local storage for `website.com`.  How am I able to obtain the local storage of `domain.com`? There must be a way since navigating to `website.com` set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the local storage of domain.com:

```
driver.get("website.com")
driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem('specialinfo')")
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: No.  It will only return items beloing to "website.com"